# Single word for: calculator "for whole dataset at a time"

Tags: single-word-requests

I am writing a title for a research paper, which presents a new calculation method (calculator) for identifying patients comorbidity status. **This method allows calculating comorbidity statuses for all patients in data at once (no need for one-by-one calculations)**. Basically, insert your data and this will add comorbidity statuses for all patients.

How to write the "whole-dataset" characteristic in English?

> Novel **dataset/dataset-wide/whole-dataset/...** calculator for identifying patient's comorbidity status

Comment: Have you ruled out the three options in your sample sentence?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with "whole-dataset"  It baffles me that people writing papers use the most abstruse words they can find. Is this supposed to impress their readers? All it does is to hide their work in a morass of other incomprehensible vocabulation.  (intentional irony)

**My suggestion**

Novel whole-dataset calculator for identifying patient's comorbidity status

I might add "efficient" because that is what makes the difference when computing.

---

P.S. Just checking. Do you mean "patient's" or "patients'".  If the former, then I think you are definitive onto something very useful.

Answer (score 0):

The term *Data-corpus* has come into use in the last 20 or 30 years (this is apparent in google ngram). It extends the following meaning by applying *corpus* to data in general rather than data on written or spoken material.

> Corpus = “ a collection of written or spoken material stored on a computer and used to find out how language is used”
>
> [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/corpus)

Answer (score 0):

"Parallel" is the computing term.  The results are being calculated "in parallel".

Comment: Highly unlikely unless multiple processors are being used.

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica - Doesn't require multiple processors.

Comment: Then it's not truly in parallel. Anything performed on a single processor is done sequentially. Not only that but the data must be read sequentially unless this is a very novel algorithm indeed.

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica - Depends on your point of view.

Answer (score 0):

As new-patient data is immediately integrated, you might call it an

> *Integrative* calculator for identifying patient's comorbidity status